# No space left on device error with pyspark aws glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am using AWS glue to extract dynamoDB items into S3. I read all the items using the pyspark and was glue and apply a transformation on the items retrieved from DynamoDB and write into S3. But I always run into the error "**No space left on device**."

The worker type I use is G.1X, and each worker maps to 1 DPU (4 vCPU, 16 GB of memory, 64 GB disk), and the size of dynamoDB is 6GB.

Based on the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-shuffle-manager.html), **During a shuffle, data is written to disk and transferred across the network. As a result, the shuffle operation is bound to local disk capacity** How can I set the shuffling programmatically?  Please find my sample code below,

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.transforms import Map
from awsglue.transforms import Filter
from pyspark import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
glue_context = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())



# mytable got id and uri
resources_table_dynamic_frame = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.input.tableName": "my_table",
        "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent": "0.4",
        "dynamodb.splits": "8"
    }
)

# Filter out rows whose ids are same
def filter_new_id(dynamicRecord):
    uri = dynamicRecord['Uri']
    uri_split = uri.split(":")
    # Get the internal ID
    internal_id = uri_split[1]
    print(dynamicRecord)

    if internal_id == dynamicRecord['id']:
        return False

    return True


# Keep only the items whose IDs are different.
resource_with_old_id = Filter.apply(
    frame=resources_table_dynamic_frame,
    f=lambda x: filter_new_id(x),
    transformation_ctx='resource_with_old_id'
)

glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=resource_with_old_id,
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://path/"},
    format="json"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed this issue with the following tweak in the code posted in OP.

```
resources_table_dynamic_frame = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
   connection_type="dynamodb",
   connection_options={
       "dynamodb.input.tableName": "my_table",
       "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent": "0.5",
       "dynamodb.splits": "200"
   },
   additional_options={
      "boundedFiles" : "30000"
   }
)
```

I added boundedFiles as suggested in AWS doc [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimizing-spark-applications-with-workload-partitioning-in-aws-glue/) and increased the `dynamodb.splits` to make it work for me.